# How to solve differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve the differential equation ? $$\frac{dy}{dx} + 2x\sin(y) = 2.$$ 
I have no ideas for a solution.

Comment: First, why do you think it can be solved by hand ? Only a few types of differential equations can be solved manually. Your differential equation seems extremely difficult to solve w/o a computer. So may I ask where you got it from ?

Comment: Think about $x(y)$ instead of $y(x)$

Comment: @rsadhvika I've got this equation from my teacher he said that it converges to Riccati's equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitution: $$ t(x) = tg(\frac{y}{2}), $$
  $$ y = 2 \ arctg(t), $$
  $$ y' = \frac{2 t'}{1 + t^2}, $$
  $$ sin(y) = \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2}. $$
We get: $$ \frac{2 t'}{1 + t^2} + 2x \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2} = 2$$
$$ t' + 2xt = 1 + t^2 $$ 
 Substitution: $$ z = t - x $$
 Riccati equation: $$ z' = z^2 - x^2. $$